# Password change failure

Tags: php, laravel-9

Hello everyone please I have written a controller function that accepts a form input containing 3 fields, oldpassword newpassword and confirmpassword fields. It is supposed to check the oldpassword against what's in the system and replace it with newpassword dd of the request shows that my controller function receives the request but can not save the new password. Please what am I doing wrong?

this is my controller function

```
public function update_password (Request $request)
{
    // dd($request);
    $request->validate([
        'oldpassword' => ['required','string','min:8'],
        'newpassword' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed']
    ]);

    $currentPasswordStatus = Hash::check($request->oldpassword, auth()->user()->password);
    if($currentPasswordStatus){

        User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id)->update([
            'password' => Hash::make($request->newpassword),

        ]);

        dd($request->password);
        return redirect()->route('profile')->with('message','Password Updated Successfully');

    }else{

        return redirect()->back()->with('message','Current Password does not match with Old Password');
    }
}
```

these are my route

Route::post('update_password', [\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController::class, 'update_password'])->name('change_password');
Route::get('update_password',[\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisteredUserController::class, 'edit_password'])->name('edit_password');

this is my input form

```
 <div class="row g-7">

                                    <form class="box" style="top: 50rem" method="POST"
                                        action="{{ route('change_password') }}">
                                        @csrf
                                        <div>
                                            <label class="font-italic mb-1" style="padding: 1rem">Enter Old Password:
                                            </label>
                                            <span><input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password"
                                                    name="oldpassword" required /></span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div>
                                            <label class="font-italic mb-1" style="padding: 1rem">Enter New Password:
                                            </label>
                                            <span><input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password"
                                                    name="newpassword" required /></span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div>
                                            <label class="font-italic mb-1" style="padding: 1rem">Confirm New Password:
                                            </label>
                                            <span><input id="password" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="password"
                                                    name="confirm" required /></span>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="button">
                                            <button type="submit"
                                                class="btn btn-danger text-uppercase mr-2 px-4">reset
                                            </button>
                                        </div>

                                    </form>

                                </div>
```

Comment: why you tagi with two different laravel versions? please keep only one that reflects the version you use

Answer (score 0):

You're validating against `$request->newpassword`, but attempting to update using `$request->password`.

Also, be careful with your typo of `return redirect()->routte('profile')`. Only one 't' in route.

Comment: Hello, Seemly. Thanks for your feedback please am so sorry for the typo. After correcting it and also changing the password to newpassword for the update function, it still doesn't work

Comment: There are so many questions that are raised for me: is the request validating successfully? I'd use `min_digits` rather than `min`. Read the documentation as to why I suggest this. Do you successfully enter the `if` condition?